# Getting "unauthorized_client" when trying to login using Microsoft account

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

In my IS4's Startup.cs:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddMicrosoftAccount(o =>
        {
            o.SignInScheme = IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
            o.ClientId = "clientId";
            o.ClientSecret = "clientSecret";
        });
```

I have defined the scope:

- openid
- profile

And I get the error after I tried to login:

unauthorized_client: The client does not exist or is not enabled for consumers. If you are the application developer, configure a new application through the App Registrations in the Azure Portal at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908.

It's a web app. So what am I doing wrong here:

I assume the client ID is this:
[image]

And my client secret is this:
[image]

I have also set up the redirect URI:

[image]

Comment: Any update this issue?

Comment: Not yet, I've been busy with a different issues so this will have to wait :) I know this is probably just a quick test, but I'm on a deadline with the other one.

Answer (score 13):

The error means the `Supported account types` are not set for the personal account(Microsoft account in your case).

To solve the issue, navigate to the `Manifest` of your App registration, set the two properties [`accessTokenAcceptedVersion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#accesstokenacceptedversion-attribute) and [`signInAudience`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#signinaudience-attribute) like below.

```
"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
"signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"
```

When you save the setting, make sure your app meets the requirement of the [validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/supported-accounts-validation), otherwise there will be some errors.

Comment: Really appreciate your response, JW! I couldn't find any instructions on that in the docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-microsoft-account?pivots=b2c-user-flow#prerequisites

Comment: Thanks for this! I didn't have the option to select Personal Account when registering the application through the portal UI.